# Creating dictionary from two lists of webscraped data

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

so I have this webdata that I scraped from a product website. I scraped it using BeautifulSoup, and scraped multiple pages from the product website. I get two lists from the scraper, one is of the specification and the other is the data for specification.
Here is an example:

```
Blade length : 2.97/1.97" 
Blade Thickness : 0.090/2.54" 
Open Length :   7.05/6.05" 
Closed Length:  4.08" | 9.78cm
Handle Thickness:   0.40" | 10.16mm
Weight: 2.28oz | 64.64g
```

I want to get the left hand side to be a Key for dictionary and the right hand side to be the value. The ultimate goal is to put it in a csv where I can have the left hand side to be the column headers for the data in the right hand side. Since I am scraping multiple pages, the left hand side repeats itself and the there are multiple values of the right hand side.

So the desired output should be something like this:

```
 Blade Length. | | Blade Thickness|| Open Length |--etc etc
|------------- | |----------------||-------------| 
| 2.97/1.97"   | |  4.34/12.54    ||  1.23/5.65  |  
| 4.24/2.23"   | |  2.34/5.63     ||  5.43/2.90  |  
| 3.54/2.65    | |  2.57/6.54     ||  6.90/4.20  |  
| 7.65/5/43    | |  4.65/3.56     ||  3.32/4.54  |
```

so if there is a better way to do this than dictionaries then please let me know!

The HTML is something like this:

```
<table class="specifications-table">
     <tbody>
               <tr>
                    <th class="col label">Blade Length:</th>
                    <td class="col value">2.97/1.97"</td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                    <th class="col label">Blade Thickness:</th>
                    <td class="col value">0.090"</td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                    <th class="col label">Open Length: </th>
                    <td class="col value">7.05/6.05"</td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                    <th class="col label">Closed Length: </th>
                    <td class="col value">4.08"</td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                    <th class="col label">Handle Thickness:</th>
                    <td class="col value">0.40" </td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                    <th class="col label">Weight:</th>
                    <td class="col value">2.28oz</td>
               </tr>
      </tbody>
</table>
```

Here is my attempt to get this data:

```
Specs = []
Specs_Datas = defaultdict(list)
Specs2 = []
for links in product_links:
    HTML2 = requests.get(links, HEADER)
    Booti2 = soup(HTML2.content,"html.parser") 
    table_feature = Booti2.select_one('#product-attribute-specs-table')
    #find all rows
    try:
        for S in Booti2.find_all('th', attrs ={'class': 'col label'}):
            Specs.append(S.text.replace('\n', '').strip())
            unique_specs = np.unique(Specs).tolist()
            while unique_specs in Specs:
                for SD in Booti2.find_all('td', attrs ={'class': 'col value'}):
                    Specs2.append(SD.text.replace('\n', '').strip())
                    Specs_Datas[unique_specs] = []
                    Specs_Datas[unique_specs].update(SD.text.replace('\n', '').strip())
            #Specs.append(S.text.replace('\n', '').strip())
            
    except:
        continue
```

Any help would be appreciated!!
Thank you so much!!!

Comment: What would a desired output look like?

Comment: I want it as a table with the Blade thickness, Blade length etc should be column headers and all its values as its rows.

Comment: It is in the question. The table shown in the question is the desired output!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can let pandas parse the `<table>` tag and transpose it. Then you append the transposed tables into a result_df.

It's tough to show with the limited code you have here, but this is the basic idea:

import pandas as pd

```
html1 = '''<table class="specifications-table">
     <tbody>
               <tr>
                    <th class="col label">Blade Length:</th>
                    <td class="col value">2.97/1.97"</td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                    <th class="col label">Blade Thickness:</th>
                    <td class="col value">0.090"</td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                    <th class="col label">Open Length: </th>
                    <td class="col value">7.05/6.05"</td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                    <th class="col label">Closed Length: </th>
                    <td class="col value">4.08"</td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                    <th class="col label">Handle Thickness:</th>
                    <td class="col value">0.40" </td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                    <th class="col label">Weight:</th>
                    <td class="col value">2.28oz</td>
               </tr>
      </tbody>
</table>'''

html2 = '''<table class="specifications-table">
     <tbody>
               <tr>
                    <th class="col label">Blade Length:</th>
                    <td class="col value">4.33/1.15"</td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                    <th class="col label">Blade Thickness:</th>
                    <td class="col value">0.150"</td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                    <th class="col label">Open Length: </th>
                    <td class="col value">9.05/8.05"</td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                    <th class="col label">Closed Length: </th>
                    <td class="col value">3.15"</td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                    <th class="col label">Handle Thickness:</th>
                    <td class="col value">0.75" </td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                    <th class="col label">Weight:</th>
                    <td class="col value">4.69oz</td>
               </tr>
      </tbody>
</table>'''
```

So given your urls/htmls:

```
tables = [html1, html2]
final_df = pd.DataFrame()
for html in tables:
    df = pd.read_html(html)[0].set_index(0).T
    final_df = final_df.append(df, sort=False).reset_index(drop=True)
```

**Output:**

```
print(final_df.to_string())
0 Blade Length: Blade Thickness: Open Length: Closed Length: Handle Thickness: Weight:
0    2.97/1.97"           0.090"   7.05/6.05"          4.08"             0.40"  2.28oz
1    4.33/1.15"           0.150"   9.05/8.05"          3.15"             0.75"  4.69oz
```

Comment: I like this as a more wholistic reframing of the task.

Comment: Thank you so much! Just one thing, when I do it in multiple pages, I get the blade length, blade thickness, basically df[0] to be repetitive, is there a way to get them all together and not repeat? Maybe a way to group them together?

Comment: Ya we can append or concat them together. I’ll edit this solution to show you tomorrow morning.

Comment: So you would just iterate through the htmls, or urls, or what ever it is that produces those htmls for you. See the example above.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you actually have two lists as:

```py
specs = [
    "Blade length",
    "Blade Thickness",
    "Open Length",
    "Closed Length",
    "Handle Thickness",
    "Weight"
]
```

and

```py
spec_data = [
    "2.97/1.97\"",
    "0.090/2.54\"",
    "7.05/6.05\"",
    "4.08\" | 9.78cm",
    "0.40\" | 10.16mm",
    "2.28oz | 64.64g"
]
```

The easiest path might be to `zip()` them together:

```py
specs_reshaped = [
    {key: value for key, value in zip(specs, spec_data)}
]
```

Then use a `DictWriter()`

```py
with open("output.csv", "w", newline="", encoding="utf-8") as file_out:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(file_out, fieldnames=specs)
    writer.writeheader()
    writer.writerows(specs_reshaped)
```

This produces a file like:

```
Blade length,Blade Thickness,Open Length,Closed Length,Handle Thickness,Weight
"2.97/1.97""","0.090/2.54""","7.05/6.05""","4.08"" | 9.78cm","0.40"" | 10.16mm",2.28oz | 64.64g
```